# Finding two integers appearing in all pairs

Tags: algorithm

I recently came across this question and cannot come up with a good solution.

You are given m pairs of integers.  Each integer is between 1 and n, inclusive.  Find two integers x and y  (1 <= x < y <= n) such that in each pair at least one integer is equal to x OR y.

For example, give (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) the integers would be 2,4

It seem like there should be a O(n) solution but all I have come up with is an awful brut force attempt.

```
pair<int, int> AwefulPairFinding(vector< pair<int,int> > pairs)
{
    vector<int> vec;

    for(const auto& p : pairs)
    {
        vec.push_back(p.first);
        vec.push_back(p.second);
    }
    //remove duplicates
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());

    // test pairs
    for (auto j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
    {
        for (auto k = j+1; k < vec.size()-1; k++)
        {
            if (2 == vec[j] && 4 == vec[k])
                cout << "";
            int matches = 0;
            for (const auto& p : pairs)
            {
                if (p.first == vec[j] || p.second == vec[j] || p.first == vec[k] || p.second == vec[k])
                    ++matches;
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (matches == pairs.size())
                return make_pair(vec[j], vec[k]);
        }
    }
    return make_pair(0, 0);    
}
```

Comment: In each pair is the first element less than or equal to second element?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Set Coverage problem", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: what is the expected answer in following cases -  Case I - `(1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (2,5) (2,6) `, Case II - `(1,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6)`?

Answer (score 3):

Take the first pair in your list, say `(a, b)`. Search through the remaining pairs for one that's distinct. If you didn't find one, `(a, b)` is a pair of integers that intersects with every other pair and you're done. If you did find one, say `(c, d)`, then you have only four possibilities for the two integers: `(a, c)`, `(a, d)`, `(b, c)`, `(b, d)`. Go through the all the pairs, and see if any of these four possibilities work.

This is clearly O(n) since you go through all the pairs twice, and perform a bounded amount of work on each.

Note: If your pairs can be equal, and you have an equal pair `(a, a)`, then `a` must be one of the two integers. Find the other integer by seeing if there's any value in common with the remaining pairs that don't contain an `a`. Note that as soon as you find a pair that doesn't contain `a` there can be only 2 choices (or 1 if it's also paired). (Actually, with careful coding, this paired case falls under the first case, except you have to be careful never to choose `(a, a)` as your two integers).

Here's some example Python code that doesn't try to be efficient, and doesn't handle the edge-case of returning the same integer twice if that integer is a cover (under some circumstances). It runs in O(n) time though.

```
def distinct(p, q):
    return p[0] != q[0] and p[0] != q[1] and p[1] != q[0] and p[1] != q[1]

def find_2cover(ps):
    c, d = None, None
    for q in ps:
        if distinct(ps[0], q):
            c, d = q
            break
    else:
        return ps[0]
    a, b = ps[0]
    choices = [(a, c), (a, d), (b, c), (b, d)]
    for q in ps:
        remove = []
        for c in choices:
            if distinct(q, c):
                remove.append(c)
        if remove:
            choices = [c for c in choices if c not in remove]
    return choices[0] if choices else None


print(find_2cover([(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5)]))
```

Output:

```
(2, 4)
```

Comment: Could you write it down in a (pseudo) code, I personally don't really see it from your answer - I dare say you are describing like ```O(n^2)```...

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I included some Python. I dare say it's O(n) and not O(n^2) :)